# TypeError при int() в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, циклы, словари

У меня есть словарь, значения в котором представлены списком строк, содержащих целые числа: `{35: ["85", "95"]}`.

Используя этот код, я хотел заменить все строковые значения на аналогичные целочисленные:

```
    TempList = []
    for key in graph:
        for value in graph[key]:
            if isinstance(value, str):
                TempList.extend(int(value))
        graph.setdefault(key, TempList)
```

Но вылезает `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
Я не понимаю почему вылезает эта ошибка и как её исправить.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TempList.extend()` ожидает `iterable` объект (т.е. объект у которого имплементированы методы:  `__iter__()` или `__getitem__()`) в качестве аргумента

```
In [85]: TempList.extend?
Docstring: L.extend(iterable) -> None -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

попробуйте использовать: `TempList.append(...)`

Comment: Спасибо, это убрало ошибку. Но значения всё равно остаются строковые. То есть TempList не устанавливается для key. При том, что в самом TempList целочисленные значения. Не понимаю почему

Comment: Изменил graph.setdefault(key, TempList) на graph[key] = TempList и заработало.